# нормальная ли такая реализация издателя и подписчика на си?

Tags: linux, c

Мне конечно понятно как это делается в ооп. Типа создаётся интерфейс в котором указываются методы, которые надо переопределить в классе потомке. Но я так привык к си, что когда хочу что-то реализовать, то думаю сишным мышлением, а не объектно-ориентированным. И тут утром я думаю, что-то захотелось реализовать такой код. Чтобы подписчику можно было подписаться на события. Хочу спросить у вас, нормальная ли для си такая реализация? Ну как бы ваше мнение хочу прочитать. Вот какие функции я реализовал.

```
/*
 * init_publisher - инициализировать издателя. 
 * @type = это тип издателя. Например в enum указывает enum { TRADE, NEWS }, к каждому издателю можно подписаться нескольким функциям.
 * @subscribe = это функция указатель. в эту фукнцию издатель будет отправлять события и данные.
 */
void init_publisher ( int type, void (*subscribe) (void *event, void *data), void *data );
/*
 * отправить событие.
 * @type = если например в init_publisher вы задали TRADE, то в send_event в TRADE отправяться событие, которое вы укажите.
 * @event = событие. можно передать любые данные.
 */
void send_event ( int type, void *event );
/*
 * отписаться от издателя.
 * @type = тип издателя.
 * @subscribe = функция указатель. её надо указать, чтобы в этом типе удалить эту функцию от подписки.
 */
void delete_publisher ( int type, void (*subscribe) ( void *event, void *data ) );
```

Это используется настолько просто, что сразу отсекает все объектно-ориентированные подходы. Ну это как мне кажется.

и я вот щас сделал пример, чтобы показать как пользоваться.

```
#include "publisher.h"

enum { TRADE, NEWS };

struct human {
        int number;
};

void sub_trade ( void *event, void *data ) {
        struct human *human = ( struct human * ) data;
        int money = ( int ) event;
        printf ( "%d получил %d\n", human->number, money );

}

void sub_news ( void *event, void *data ) {
        struct human *human = ( struct human * ) data;
        int news = ( int ) event;
        printf ( "%d читает %d\n", human->number, news );
}
int main ( ) {
        struct human human[2] = {
                { 1 },
                { 2 }
        };

        init_publisher ( TRADE, sub_trade, &human[0] );
        init_publisher ( TRADE, sub_trade, &human[1] );
        init_publisher ( NEWS, sub_news, &human[0] );

        for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
                if ( i % 10 == 0 ) send_event ( TRADE, 10 );
                if ( i % 20 == 0 ) send_event ( NEWS, 1 );
        }

}
```

правда здорово? вот код на [github](https://github.com/xverizex/publisher). если хотите подсказать что нибудь, то всегда рад помощи.

а вот сам код, реализация издателя. есть ли в нем ошибка?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*subs) (void *event, void *data);

static struct publisher {
    int *types;
    int size;
    struct sub {
        int size;
        subs *subscribe;
        void **data;
    } *sub;
} *pb;

void init_publisher ( int type, void (*subscribe) ( void *event, void *data ), void *data ) {
    if ( !pb ) {
        pb = calloc ( 1, sizeof ( struct publisher ) );
        pb->types = calloc ( 0, sizeof ( int ) );
        pb->sub = calloc ( 0, sizeof ( struct sub ) );
    }   
    for ( int i = 0; i < pb->size; i++ ) {
        if ( pb->types[i] != type ) continue;

        pb->sub[i].subscribe = realloc ( pb->sub[i].subscribe, sizeof ( subs ) * ( pb->sub[i].size + 1 ) );
        pb->sub[i].data = realloc ( pb->sub[i].data, sizeof ( void * ) * ( pb->sub[i].size + 1 ) );
        int size = pb->sub[i].size;
        pb->sub[i].subscribe[size] = subscribe;
        pb->sub[i].data[size] = data;
        pb->sub[i].size++;
        return;
    }
    pb->types = realloc ( pb->types, sizeof ( int ) * ( pb->size + 1 ) );
    pb->sub = realloc ( pb->sub, sizeof ( struct sub ) * ( pb->size + 1 ) );
    pb->sub[pb->size].subscribe = calloc ( 1, sizeof ( subs ) );
    pb->sub[pb->size].data = calloc ( 1, sizeof ( void * ) );
    pb->types[pb->size] = type;
    pb->sub[pb->size].subscribe[0] = subscribe;
    pb->sub[pb->size].data[0] = data;
    pb->sub[pb->size].size = 1;
    pb->size++;
}

void delete_publisher ( int type, void (*subscribe) ( void *event, void *data ) ) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < pb->size; i++ ) {
        if ( pb->types[i] != type ) continue;

        for ( int ii = 0; ii < pb->sub[i].size; ii++ ) {
            if ( pb->sub[i].subscribe[ii] == subscribe ) {
                int size = pb->sub[i].size;
                int pos = size == ii - 1 ? ii : ii + 1;
                int ss = size == ii - 1 ? 0 : size - ii;
                int dst = ii;
                int src = pos;
                for ( int iii = pos; iii < size; iii++ ) {
                    pb->sub[i].subscribe[dst] = pb->sub[i].subscribe[src];
                    pb->sub[i].data[dst], pb->sub[i].data[src];
                    dst++; src++;
                }
                size = --pb->sub[i].size;
                pb->sub[i].subscribe = realloc ( pb->sub[i].subscribe, size * sizeof ( subs ) );
                pb->sub[i].data = realloc ( pb->sub[i].data, size * sizeof ( void * ) );
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

void send_event ( int type, void *event ) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < pb->size; i++ ) {
        if ( pb->types[i] != type ) continue;

        for ( int ii = 0; ii < pb->sub[i].size; ii++ ) {
            pb->sub[i].subscribe[ii] ( event, pb->sub[i].data[ii] );
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Такое глобальное замечание - не к конкретному коду. Класс в С - это просто структура с набором функций для работы с ней. Естественно, при этом отсутствует *строгая* инкапсуляция, но наследование и полиморфизм вполне можно реализовать...

Comment: @Harry ну да, можно. типа того. такое же сделали gobject в glib. но блин. я думаю что в подписчике и издателе на си не нужно реализовывать объектно-ориентированные средства.

Comment: ООП вообще не нужно пихать во все дыры, как это сейчас принято, а использовать тогда, когда это необходимо. Ясное дело, код нормальный. Единственное, я бы  объявил тип указателя на функцию через typedef, и использовал бы его уже в качестве параметра. Так компактнее и легче воспринимается.

Comment: warnings вас вообще не волнуют? По крайней мере в `publisher.h` я бы добавил макрос -- `#define SEND_EVENT(t, e) send_event(t, (void *)(e))` (да и в файле с main при присваивании `money` надо бы явно привести тип через подходящий переносимый размер (скажем `size_t`)), а также  сделал бы все функции  возвращающими  результат (успешно или ошибка).

Comment: @avp хорошо спасибо. но предупреждения компилятора меня не волновали. я же знаю что я делаю.

Comment: @avp что-то у меня компилятор ругается на то, что неизвестны переменные в SEND_EVENT. Не пойму. чето писал сначала, вроде сработало, а щас опять ошибки и почему, не понятно.

Comment: @xverizex, покажите (например, в **Update** текста вопроса) код, где компилятор ругается (и вывод компилятора с руганью). А предупреждения всегда должны волновать, надо компилировать с `-Wall` (и м.б. даже с `-Wextra`)

Comment: Где реализации всех этих функций (`init_publisher`, `send_event`, `delete_publisher`)? Из приведенного кода совершенно непонятно, каким образом подписчики, зарегистрированные в `init_publisher`, потом будут получать оповещения. Наличие фраз типа "ооп отстой" и "сишное мышление" при использовании прямолинейного ООП в интерфейсе выглядят откровенно глупо.

Comment: @user7860670 как не понятно? вот например подписчик это функция. например sub_trade. ты подписываешься на издателя TRADE и указываешь, что если будут какие то события, то пусть он шлет их в эту функцию sub_trade. и всё. когда нужно отослать событие, вызывает send_event ( TRADE, [событие] )

Comment: @user7860670 а реализация на github. я же ссылку привел.

Comment: @avp ну так если я знаю что нет ошибки в коде, то что мне компилятор. всё же работает правильно.

Comment: @xverizex, я ни на чем не настаиваю, если пишите только для себя, то все равно (даже если у вас куча run time ошибок). Только учтите, что выкладывая программы в github вы адресуете их другим людям, которые получив код, компилируемый с предупреждениями будут не слишком довольны (со всеми вытекающими...)

Comment: Какой смысл в `calloc(0, ...)`?

Comment: @avp ну я думаю что так правильно делать. где-то там создается структура, которая хранит сколько памяти выделено для указателя. потом я эту память увеличиваю или уменьшаю с помощью realloc. а почему ноль делаю, потому что записывать данные пока не требуется. и это сделано для правильной работы счетчика, который увеличивается когда происходит изменения.

Comment: @xverizex, счетчики у вас в этот момент правильные, память в структуре верхнего уровня обнулена, `free()` с полученными указателями вы нигде не делаете, дальше в любом случае вы выйдете на realloc c правильными счетчиками. Вот и вся логика в этой части программы. Т.о. сами вызовы `calloc(0, ...)`-ов тут не нужны.